# Как использовать git pull так, чтобы один из файлов не перезаписывался?

Tags: git, git-pull

Как использовать git pull так, чтобы один из файлов не перезаписывался?

Comment: Попробуйте: git update-index --assume-unchanged file_name.txt

Comment: вывести его из-под контроля системы управления версиями.